# sys.dm_exec_sql_text returns NULL in dbid, objectid, and number columns, but not text

Tags: sql-server, dmv

This is something that's bugged me though has never caused any real issues as I can generally locate this information by other means, but can someone explain why `NULL` may be returned in the `dbid`, `objectid`, and `number` columns from the `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` DMV, yet yield results in the `text` column?  I understand why output would return inversely (e.g. all columns but `text` would yield data), but I've seen this behavior a number of times across a number of SQL Server versions and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql) doesn't seem to imply this should be possible, or I'm just reading it wrong.

Here's an example of the query I'm running:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
      t.*
    , s.*
    , c.*
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
        LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c
               ON c.most_recent_sql_handle = s.sql_handle
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) t
WHERE s.execution_count > 1 AND DATEDIFF (second, creation_time, GETDATE()) > 0
        AND t.dbid IS NULL
```

Here's a sample of one of the results from the `text` column which implies this isn't related to temporary objects which is what I would normally guess to be the cause.

```
select * from [dbo].[Map_ProviderSpecialty]
```

What situation is occurring where these columns are returning `NULL` values?

Comment: I wouldn't expect dbid to be NULL, but object_id would be NULL for ad hoc statements (when there is no object). Your sample statement certainly looks like an ad hoc statement. But that doesn't explain the null dbid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design as of now. There is a [feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32899729-sys-dm-exec-sql-text-dbid-is-not-always-populated) about this problem.

**sys.dm_exec_query_stats DBID column NULL for dynamic SQL - by Theo Ekelmans**

But at the end there is a comment:

> Thank you for the feedback! We will consider it for the next release
> of SQL Server.

There is also some workaround as mentioned by Erik Darling:

> If you need that data, try adding `CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) AS p` -- you should get at least dbid from there, though `objectid` will still be `NULL` for adhoc queries.

He also said:

> Well, it's sometimes available in two other related views:
>
> - dm_exec_query_plan
> - dm_exec_plan_attributes
>
> Those take plan handle instead of SQL handle though

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to me that dbid and objectid could be NULL for SQL not executed through a stored prodedure.  For example, which database and object should represent the following ad hoc query?

```
USE [Database1]

SELECT *
FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Table2] 
INNER JOIN [Database3].[dbo].[Table3]
```

My guess is that by design, SQL does not want deal with trying to make a decision on which of the three databases to pick to represent the statement in the sys.dm_exec_sql_text() results.

Answer (score -2):

The db_id of the current database. If the code does NOT specify the database which database would get used.?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/200177)